# In reference to the mentioned code, the expected result="ECTSTRI" but the actual result="ECTTRI"

Tags: java

Given a new string as input, create a new string where the letter half appears first. If the string is of odd length then the middle char remains in its position.

I am able to print the required string with even string length but facing some issues with the strings of odd length, as in case of odd string length the middle character should be at its own place. how to do this?

```
String str = "TRISECT";
int len = str.length();
int halflen = len / 2;
String newstr = "";
String zstr = "";
if(len%2==0){
    for (int i = 0; i < halflen; i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        newstr = newstr + ch;
    }
    for (int j = halflen; j < len; j++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(j);
        zstr = zstr + ch;
    }
    System.out.println(zstr + newstr);
}else{
    for (int i = 0; i < halflen; i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        newstr = newstr + ch;
    }
    for (int j = halflen + 1; j < len; j++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(j);
        zstr = zstr + ch;
    }
    System.out.println(zstr + newstr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add

```
   System.out.println(zstr+str.charAt(halflen)+newstr);
```

To your print in which you satisfy the odd length condition, it should do the trick.

What is happening is that, since you're getting half the length of your string to split it in half (and saving that value in the halflen variable), your for won't catch the character that is at the halflen position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String str = "TRISECT";
    int len = str.length();
    int halflen = len / 2;
    String newstr = "";
    String zstr = "";
    if(len%2==0){
        for (int i = 0; i < halflen; i++) {
            char ch = str.charAt(i);
            newstr = newstr + ch;
        }
        for (int j = halflen; j < len; j++) {
            char ch = str.charAt(j);
            zstr = zstr + ch;
        }
        System.out.println(zstr + newstr);
    }else{
        for (int i = 0; i < halflen; i++) {
            char ch = str.charAt(i);
            newstr = newstr + ch;
        }
        char middle;
        middle = str.charAt(halflen);

        for (int j = halflen + 1; j < len; j++) {
            char ch = str.charAt(j);
            zstr = zstr + ch;
        }
        System.out.println(zstr +middle+ newstr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
String str = "TRISECT";
        int len = str.length();
        int halflen = len / 2;
        String newstr = "";
        String zstr = "";
        if(len%2==0){
            for (int i = 0; i < halflen; i++) {
                char ch = str.charAt(i);
                newstr = newstr + ch;
            }
            for (int j = halflen; j < len; j++) {
                char ch = str.charAt(j);
                zstr = zstr + ch;
            }
            System.out.println(zstr + newstr);
        }else{
            for (int i = 0; i < halflen; i++) {
                char ch = str.charAt(i);
                newstr = newstr + ch;
            }
            char middle = str.charAt(halflen);

            for (int j = halflen+1; j < len; j++) {
                char ch = str.charAt(j);
                zstr = zstr + ch;
            }
            System.out.println(zstr +middle+ newstr);
        }
```

In your code you are leaving the middle character behind.

Comment: No I dint copied your ans.

Comment: What different has your answer? And the spaces in the last `system.out` are the same.

Comment: sorry but if I have copied your code then i wont be knowing what is wrong with the code, that means i have debug the code and then posted the ans..